# how do i store the value of stars rating in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hi I have form that contains Ratings, Name, email, and comments. I am able to insert the user input data for  name, email and comments. But don't know how to store the star ratings in database. Anyone please help me. thanks

```
      <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$ratings = $_POST['ratings'];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imakr");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$res = mysqli_query($link, "insert into imakr.customer_review(name, email, comments, ratings) values('$name','$email','$comments', '$ratings')");

    if($res)
    {
        echo "Your feedback is saved";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " OOPs!! there is some error. Please check the fields";
    }

}
?>

<form id="customer_review" name="cust_rev"action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <table width="535" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Rate This Product:
      </td>
      <td>
      <span id="rateStatus">Rate Me...</span>
<span id="ratingSaved">Rating Saved!</span> 

<div id="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_1" title="Poor" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"><span class="ratings">1</span></a>
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_2" title="Not Bad" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"><span class="ratings">2</span></a>
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_3" title="Pretty Good" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"><span class="ratings">3</span></a>
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_4" title="Excellent" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"><span class="ratings">4</span></a>
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_5" title="Marvellous" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"><span class="ratings">5</span></a>
</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="129"><span class="titles">Name</span><span class="star">*</span>:</td>
      <td width="396"><label for="name"></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="titles">Email</span><span class="star">*</span>:</td>
      <td><label for="email"></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="61">Comments:</td>
      <td><label for="comments"></label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="45" rows="5" onchange="maxlength('comments', 500)"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Immediately stop using this code. It is vulnerable to SQL injection. You're using an API that is deprecated. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @Polish Prince Sorry, can you tell me why? I am a beginner.

Comment: yes it is, I would recommend using mysqli, check out this link http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @user2148257 Click the links to learn why.

Comment: @user2148257 look it up, there is even a [Wikipedia entry on SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Please give me a solution for my problem above. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the rating from the form to your script? Please be a bit more specific

Comment: I mean how can i store the rating in the database when the user clicks on the stars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden input field with the name ratings

```
<input id="ratings" type="hidden" name="ratings" value="" />
```

Then use Javascript to dynamically update the value of this input depending on which rating value has bees clicked.

Something like the following:

```
document.getElementById('ratings').value='4'
```

Alternatively if you don't want to this dynamically without submitting the form then you can use an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to submit this information to your database.

As a very huge side note and before you go any further however, **please please please stop using `mysql_*`** functions and start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). In particular look at prepared statements with bound values, unless you want to see your whole database deleted by SQL injection of course.

Comment: Hi will it store the values from  <span class=ratings>

Comment: Please explain me i didn't get you. Thanks

Comment: No, you can't access values inside a span using `$_POST[]` in PHP. You have to submit your ratings value as a `$_POST[]` value to access it, which is why I said to create a hidden input field called ratings and then update this value once a user clicks on one of the ratings.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand. I am not a senior developer

Comment: I neither am a senior developer sir. Do you want to do this when submitting the form as a whole or is the rating part separate to the form?

Comment: I fear that if you haven't understood what I have said up to this point that this project may be a bit too far over your head at the moment. Especially in terms of protecting yourself from SQL injection but it is something you will need to learn fast.

Comment: I want the stars to be submitted along with  the form as a whole

Comment: Then using what I have said inside my main question will work for you. Set the hidden input value named "ratings" depending on what is clicked by the user will achieve this.

Comment: Hi Peter Featherstone, Thanks your idea gave worked out for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Always a pleasure @user2148257!

Answer (score 3):

1. Pick a data type, if you're going to only store whole-number ratings, [eg: 3/5 stars] then use `TINYINT`. If you're going to store fractions of a star, [eg: 3.5/5 stars] then use `DECIMAL(2,1)`.
2. Store some identifying information about the user to prevent multiple ratings. If the user is not required to be logged in to rate something, then store their IP address along with the rating.

Comment: I want to know how do you pull the rating value from the form?